# Why does my if string == else if != statement only work for the last value in array?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a monthly calender collection view and a xml that I am parsing to get some dates. I am trying to show these dates with borders on the calendarview but am running into an issue that I'm not sure how to debug - dates that are not from the xml also show up with borders around them and then random change when you scroll to the next month and back, like this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMYyR.jpg

Here is my code for settings borders right now. Is there anything visibly wrong or missing

```
//Mark: Configure Calendar Cell
func configureCalendarCell(cell: JTAppleCell?, cellState: CellState) {
    guard let myCustomCell = cell as? CalendarCell else { return }

    //configure functions including:
    getEventDates(cell: myCustomCell, cellState: cellState)
}

//Mark: set events from XML == selected cell from Calendar
func getEventDates(cell: CalendarCell, cellState: CellState) {

        for calendarDate in tableViewDataSource {
            let datesFromCalendarXML = calendarDate.date
            //print("Found \(datesFromCalendarXML)") This prints dates parsed from XML file - See picture 1 below

            let visibleDatesToString = formatter.string(from: cellState.date)
            //print("Visible dates \(visibleDatesToString)") This prints all of the dates in the current month showing. So for September, it shows all of the dates in September. See picture 2 below

            // If there is a date match, then show a round blue border
            if datesFromCalendarXML == visibleDatesToString {

                cell.dateLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 25
                cell.dateLabel.layer.borderWidth = 3
                cell.dateLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
                cell.dateLabel.clipsToBounds = true

            // If there is no date match, show no border. I had set this to UIColor.clear.cgColor but then only the last datesFromCalendarXML Oct 30 showed as a blue, so I changed it to red and saw that random dates including the ones from the XML are being circled red.
            } else if datesFromCalendarXML != visibleDatesToString {
                cell.dateLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
                cell.dateLabel.clipsToBounds = true
            }
}
}
}

//Mark: CalendarView Delegate
extension CalendarViewController: JTAppleCalendarViewDelegate {

func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, cellForItemAt date: Date, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath) -> JTAppleCell {
    let cell = calendar.dequeueReusableJTAppleCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CalendarCell", for: indexPath) as! CalendarCell
    cell.dateLabel.text = cellState.text
    configureCalendarCell(cell:cell, cellState: cellState)
    return cell
}
}
```

It seems this only works for the last value in datesFromCalendarXML as Oct 30 shows u pwith a blue ring. The other values in the XML, Sept 1, 10, 20 and Oct 1, 10, 20 show up with red rings as do other random dates.

In my console for //print("Found (datesFromCalendarXML)" - https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYlYL.png

In my console for //print("Visible dates (visibleDatesToString)") - https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbRtA.png

Added:

I tried to just change the color of the datelabel to green and for whatever reason, that works to make only the matched dates green and does not add random other green dates. I have no idea why I can change the dateLabel.textColor and not the background - https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AKNv.jpg

```
if datesFromCalendarXML == visibleDatesToString {
                cell.dateLabel.textColor = UIColor.green

            } else if datesFromCalendarXML != visibleDatesToString {

            }
```

Comment: Are you dequeuing a reusable `JTAppleCell`? If so, that explains it.

Comment: @DanielT Yes, I have it in the cellForItemAt method

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your logic

for calendarDate in tableViewDataSource {}

The calendarDate always loop to fill the red background

pretend you in date 10, and your xml is : 10,20,30

When the date 10 check, it loop to fill it background blue, then red, then red

So use break inside  if datesFromCalendarXML == visibleDatesToString {} so it will stopped after fill blue backgrund

Comment: i want to clarify: My XML dates are Sep 1, 10, 20, Oct 1, 10, 30 and its making Oct 30 blue. So the last date is blue, not first one - this is for the same reason that you explained? I want all of the xml dates to be blue.  Also, did you see where I change dateLabel.textColor = UIColor.green. Do you know why that works and the backgroundColor does not?

Comment: I also am getting red borders around dates are not selected nor in my XML. Why does that happen? Why is it random each time a month loads

Comment: This is the correct answer. You shouldn't even *have* a loop in that method. One cell represents one date but you are looping through all the dates for every cell.

Answer (score 0):

In configureCalendarCell you are creating cell everytime. Instead of that you can use dequeueReusableCell, which actually reuses your created cell and just update new data to it. This is the main advantage of a CollectionView.

```
let cell =  collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TDCheckMarkLabelCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath)
```

First you have to set unique identifier for your cell in storyboard or XIB.

Comment: Thank you. I already have this in my cellForRowAt  method. I didn't add it to my original post because I forgot as relevant. I have added it now. I have set a cell reuse identifier.

Comment: Your issue is fixed or not ?

Comment: No, not fixed. I meant that I already have this part in my code but had not shared this in the original post. The original issue still remains. I already have the cellForItemAt, didSelectDate, didDeselectDate methods for my collectionView.  Is there anything you see that might be causing my issue?

Answer (score 0):

One of the other answers *almost* got it... You are using `dequeueReusableCell` as you are supposed to. However, you forgot or didn't realize that this means you are *reusing* cells! That means that sometimes you get a cell that has already been setup to display a border and using it to display a cell that isn't supposed to display a border. Since your function assumes that the cell doesn't have a border, it does nothing to the cell, and since the cell already has a border, it displays with a border.

There are two ways to fix this.

1. Inside your cell you can override the `prepareForReuse` method and remove any circle that may exist on the cell.
2. Finish the logic in your `getEventDates` function. Your logic doesn't say what should happen to a cell that shouldn't have either a red or a blue border, but happens to have one currently.

Comment: Thank you Daniel for this explanation. I'm still a little confused. I thought I had finished the logic in getEventDates. There are only 2 options - either the dates match (if datesFromCalendarXML == visibleDatesToString), in which case turn them blue or the dates dont match (datesFromCalendarXML != visibleDatesToString), in which case, turn them red. I had originally set it to clear instead of red which makes them disappear. However, my issue is that the dates that should match don't all show up with blue borders, only the last one does. Cont'd

Comment: My XML dates are Sep 1, 10, 20, Oct 1, 10, 30 and its making only Oct 30 blue. I only turned the "if the dates dont match (datesFromCalendarXML != visibleDatesToString)" from clear to red to see what might be happening.